# $.getJson function not working

Tags: json, twitter, getjson

```
var query1 = urlencode($('input[name="searchTerm"]').val()); //user1
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/friends/ids.json?screen_name='+ query1 +'&jsoncallback=?', 
function(data){
$('content').append(''+data.length+'');
});
```

This is a simple code that gets the json data from the url

[http://twitter.com/friends/ids.json?screen_name=Planemad&jsoncallback=?](http://twitter.com/friends/ids.json?screen_name=Planemad)

(click url to view the json data)

The data looks like this:

[6014732,1717291,14049312,1000591,13,2384071,20,14071015,813286,7517052,14279711,....]

"data.length" should give me the number of users the specified user is following.

However it doesnt seem to work for some reason.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what does alert(data) show you?

Comment: alert data now shows [6014732,1717291,140... after i added the &callback=? clause...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should the callback not be just callback=?

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know#5Parametershavecertainexpectations

```
ie http://twitter.com/friends/ids.json?screen_name=Planemad&callback=?
```

Comment: i added the & callback=? and it has started working...Also another question
Can i have two $.getJSON functions on the same page?
if not wat can i do?

Comment: jus checked it out...yes two $.getJSON functions can run on the same page